# Bootstrap 3 div over jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, z-index

I am using Bootstrap 3, and have a problem getting a div to sit over a jumbotron header.
I am using the jumbotron class to give me a full width, responsive header with a background image as below...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">text here</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">text here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the rest of the site...

```
 <div class="container">rest of site goes here
 </div>
```

What I want to do is have my entire site/container BELOW the jumbotron - slide up and cover half of it's height. Obviously as is, the container for the site content is cleared below the jumbotron, but i need a solution to get it up about 100px to cover the lower half of jumbotron.

I have tried both z-index methods and absolute positioning but can't get either to work. Any suggestions?

A SAMPLE TO WORK WITH HERE - http://jsfiddle.net/9b9Da/7/

Comment: There is no `.container-fluid` rule in Bootstrap 3, unless that's your own class style.

Comment: so i can remove that entire div that wraps my jumbotron above? ah yes. looks like i can. Any idoeas on how i can now 'float; the site content div over the jumbo?

Comment: I need the content to move up to cover the jumbotron. For example, if jumbo is 500px high, i need the content to start at 250px from the top of page - NOT completely under the jumbo at 500px from top. that make sense?

Comment: here is an update - http://jsfiddle.net/9b9Da/7/

Comment: Yes Bootstrap 3 has .container-fluid! http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, Bootstrap 3 doesn't have a `.container-fluid` class, which was removed in Bootstrap 2.3.2 as `.rows` are full width by default (Mobile first approach). `position: relative` was then used to offset your overlying content `<div>` to appear half way over the `.jumbotron`

```
<div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="col-md-8 jumbotext">text here</div>
     <div class="col-md-4 jumbotext">text here</div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        This content needs to float over the Jumbotron above
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #content {
       position: relative;
       bottom: 80px;
       z-index: 500;
       opacity: 0.6;
   }

   #content > .row {
       min-height: 400px;
       background: #cccccc;
   }

   .jumbotron > .jumbotext {
       z-index: 700;
   }
</style>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9b9Da/9/)</kbd>: http://jsfiddle.net/9b9Da/9/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap 3 and it has .container-fluid. It's also listed in the bootstrap docs and on the W3.

[Bootstrap classes](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_all_classes.asp)