# Bootstrap row appearing on top of jumbotron, should be below jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the markup for my index page.  I have the `jumbotron` and below it is a `row`that should be appearing below the `jumbotron`.  But it is not, it is appearing on top of the `jumbotron` for some reason I can't figure out. ( I have close to none experience in bootstrap)

```
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-billboard">
  <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Jumbotron</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum is the best
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



  <div class="row main-row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
   text1
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-3">
    text2
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-3">
   text3
    </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
    text4
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the `.css`for the `jumbotron`

```
.jumbotron-billboard .img {
    margin-bottom: 0px;

    opacity: 0.8;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000 url("gogn1.jpg") center center;

    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;


  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
.jumbotron {position:relative;padding:50px;}
.jumbotron .container {z-index:2;
 position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

It would be very nice if some-one could inform me on why the row isn't just appearing below the `jumbotron`.

Here is a link to the problem  here is a bootply for the problem bootply.com/9vxeaMQ6Xf

Comment: Make your code a snippet with CTRL+M in edit mode or provide a codepen/jsfiddle illustrating the issue you're having.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 div over jumbotron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010527/bootstrap-3-div-over-jumbotron)

Comment: @ProEvilz here is a bootply  for the problem https://www.bootply.com/9vxeaMQ6Xf

Comment: @codegirl Thanks. I have just checked your Bootply and the jumbotron is **above** the row as expected. On your screen, in the Bootply, does the jumbotron appear below the row for you?